# Concatenate three integer value UNIX

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, dos2unix

hi i am trying to concatenate three integer value in UNIX OS(SunOS 5.10). But it is not working for me .
Below is the code

```
a=2016
b=11
c=21
result="$a$b$c"
  echo "$result"
```

**OUTPUT-:**

```
2016
11
21
```

Can anyone help???

Comment: Works fine for me. So the question is: what is different in your case? What shell do you use?

Comment: Is there something else i can try please help??

Comment: Well, you could answer to a question....

Comment: Works also fine in me (Debian & Bash >4). What shell are you into?

Comment: If MS WIndows was involved in creation or moving (ftp, etc) of the file check for `\r\n` line endings with `cat -vet file` . If you see `^M$` at the end of lines, cleanup file with `dos2unix file`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
browserDate="2016-11-21"
dateConversion="${browserDate//'-'}

echo "$date Conversion"
```

Comment: The solution is nowhere what the original question meant. Also echo command is wrong, it needs a $ without the spacing and the C as caps

Comment: That was a typing mistake . Command worked perfectly for me .:)

Comment: It is still wrong, there should be no space between date and conversion

Comment: In any case, your answer does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

You need tho use printf instead of echo:

```
a=2016
b=11
c=21
result="$a\n$b\n$c"
printf $result
```

Comment: it only prints 2016.

Comment: According to this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/printf-1.html , it should work!

Comment: I really do not know what is happening.:(

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo? Are you able to echo the three variables individually properly?

Comment: Actually I got it solved what I was trying was converting my date (2016-11-21) of file  to integer value .So firstly I used substring using CUT command and got three value in different variable as shown in question and then concatenate.But that did not work.i will post how I solved it.